# Terminate camunda sub-process in two ways (conditional)

Tags: java, camunda, bpmn

I have a camunda sub process which can terminate normally (approved) or not (refused). A user task determines if the approval task is approved or refused. I tried to use a signal to leave the sub process in case the user task is refused but this triggers ALL active processes. If I have two active tasks waiting at the approval task, ALL are cancelled, which I don't want.

[image: This is my subprocess]

So I tried to use an Error end event to handle the refused gateway with a boundary event but I think there is a problem with camunda itself ? I get a NullPointerException on the subprocess as soon as I use Error event event instead of the signal :

```
public FlowElement getBpmnModelElementInstance() {
BpmnModelInstance bpmnModelInstance = getBpmnModelInstance();
if (bpmnModelInstance != null) {
  ModelElementInstance modelElementInstance = null;
  if (ExecutionListener.EVENTNAME_TAKE.equals(eventName)) {
    modelElementInstance = bpmnModelInstance.getModelElementById(transition.getId());
  } else {
    modelElementInstance = bpmnModelInstance.getModelElementById(activityId); <== activityId here is wrongly "subProcess#multiInstanceBody" instead of "subProcess" so it returns null
  }
...
```

So is there something I missed ? Should I not use Error end event but something other instead ? What solution do I have to exit my subprocess in case of refusal which is another exit of the subprocess than the approval one.